# Class won't pass by reference

Tags: c++, class, reference

The following code is printing out 343. I don't understand why it isn't taking in currentDirectory by reference and updating what it's pointing to to a subdirectory of the root instance.

I would expect it to output 344.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Directory;

struct Node{
    Node* prev;
    Node* next;
    Directory* data;
};

class Directory{
    public:
        int testValue;
        Node* subDirectories;

        void addSubdirectory(int testValue){
            Directory* newDirectory = new Directory(testValue);

            Node* elem = new Node;
            elem->prev = NULL;
            elem->data = newDirectory;

            elem->next = NULL;
            subDirectories = elem;
        }

        Directory(int x){
            testValue = x;
        }
};

void testFunction(Directory* x){
    x = x->subDirectories->data;
    cout << x->testValue;
}

int main(){
    Directory* root = new Directory(3);
    root->addSubdirectory(4);

    Directory* currentDirectory = root;

    cout << currentDirectory->testValue;

    testFunction(currentDirectory);

    cout << currentDirectory->testValue;
}
```

I've tried a simplified example that works fine:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Directory;

class Directory{
    public:
        int testValue;

        Directory(int x){
            testValue = x;
        }
};

void testFunction(Directory* x){
    x->testValue = 4;
    cout << x->testValue;
}

int main(){
    Directory* root = new Directory(3);

    Directory* currentDirectory = root;

    cout << currentDirectory->testValue;

    testFunction(currentDirectory);

    cout << currentDirectory->testValue;
}
```

This prints out 344 as expected. This one is passing it in by reference.

Comment: No, it's passing by pointer value not by reference.

Comment: That's what I figured but I can't get it working. I've tried making it a double pointer and everything

Comment: Have you tried making it a reference? I mean, your question is basically asking about passing by reference

Comment: In this particular case I don't know how to pass it in as a reference.

Comment: I'm passing it in in the same way in both the examples, yet in the second one it works and in the first it doesn't

Comment: But in the first example, you're assigning to the value you passed in, while in the second example, you're assigning to a member indirected through it. Those are *completely* different operations. In the first case, you're modifying a temporary variable that doesn't live beyond the function; in the second case, you're following a pointer to a location in memory that contains a value and modifying that, which is later read by the (identical) pointer held in `main`.

Answer (score 0):

You are making a copy of type `Directory*` and passing it into `testFunction` as an argument. That copy, x, is not a reference to the pointer root.

This is probably what you want:

```
void testFunction(Directory* &x){
    x = x->subDirectories->data;
    cout << x->testValue;
}
```

Or if you prefer the double pointer route you would have:

```
void testFunction(Directory** x){
    (*x) = (*x)->subDirectories->data;
    cout << (*x)->testValue;
}

// the call turns into
testFunction(&currentDirectory)
```

Your simplified example works because you are not actually assigning to the variable that is passed-by-value, x:

```
void testFunction(Directory* x){
    x->testValue = 4; // assigning pointed-to value, not pointer
    cout << x->testValue;
}
```

Long story short, pointer-to-type is a type in and of itself too. Passing a pointer by reference takes the same changes as any other type.

Comment: Cool that fixes it. Why does it work in my second example though?

Comment: Added. The pointer x is passed by value, the stuff x points to isn't technically 'passed' as an argument, x just tells you where it exists in memory.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that **you are passing by value not by reference**. The instance that is being passed to "testfunction()" is "currentDirectory" which is a **pointer to object**. So if you intend to pass by reference it should be like this:

```
void testFunction(Directory* &x){
    x = x->subDirectories->data;
    cout << x->testValue;
 }
```

Comment: I understand. Thanks it worked. Why does it work in my second example though?

Comment: @DavidBandel  Your second example modifies an `int` and has only a single `Directory` object. But your first example tries to modify a pointer and has two `Directory` objects. So really they're doing very different things.

Answer (score 0):

Alternately, you could create an object of the class rather than a pointer. Note, this would require you to add a copy constructor (and, hopefully, a destructor, and overloaded operator=).

```
Directory root(3);
root.addSubdirectory(4);

//Assuming you overload operator=
Directory currentDirectory = root;

cout << currentDirectory.testValue;

testFunction(currentDirectory);
```

Where

```
void testFunction(Directory & x);
```